# Free PHP framework/library for single-sign on / cross domain login

Tags: php, cross-domain, single-sign-on

I am looking for free (non GPL is better) SSO framework/library implementation or code samples.

There are many kind of SSO implementation. Sharing cookie, sharing session, one time token, associative accounts, etc, etc. (BTW, any good article compare them?)

Is there any keyword I should google and reuse before before I start to implement our own wheel.

I know OpenID, but which is too much and it is not our need. We rather keep it KISS.
We just want share the credentials of user that could save users from another login form.

Comment: After some googling I guess I found SSO is not the same as OpenID :) => See also image in my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841693/free-php-framework-library-for-single-sign-on-cross-domain-login/4841807#4841807

Answer (score 6):

After some googling I guess I found SSO is not the same as OpenID :)

[image: sso]

Did some quick [googling](http://www.google.nl/search?q=php+sso+framework#q=php+sso+framework+-java) and found these:

- http://www.single-signon.com/en/home.html (GPL)
- https://github.com/jasny/SSO ([public domain](http://www.jasny.net/copy-freely/))
- http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/using-a-sso-in-ez-publish
- http://simplesamlphp.org/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains/

Comment: I hope you haven't invented your own wheel yet.  But you are now missing two from that list:  [Single Sign-On Server/Client](http://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/) (written in PHP, MIT or LGPL license - your choice) and [Central Authentication Service](http://www.jasig.org/cas) (Java based server with a PHP client port, JA-SIG license which is kind of MIT-ish)

Comment: the jasny/SSO demo is in public domain.

Answer (score 2):

Consider OpenAuth. It's what twitter uses, and it's gaining mindshare.

The principle behind it is that when you authenticate against a trusted third party, you are prompted by an auth page on the third party domain, so it's obvious to the  user that you are logging in through them, hence the trust.

Facebook's third party login is very similar, where they show their login content in a lightbox or popup window.

Another common one is Kerberos [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29)