# Single Sign On Script / Library / API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, openid, single-sign-on

I have tried googling a lot but couldn't find a library which can provide me single-sign on feature for my website.

I am looking for similar script like stackoverflow is using for facebook, twitter, google, openid etc...

I have tried hybridauth, http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ but it's not working for me.

Could you guys please suggest me other alternatives?

Comment: you've answered your own question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841693/free-php-framework-library-for-single-sign-on-cross-domain-login

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several website using this library : http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

(formerly https://rpxnow.com/)

*I have not personally tried..*

Answer (score 0):

Why not OpenID itself? I heard good thing about it, and the same, as you specified, SO use it. There's an OpenID website that keep track of all libraries found from official OpenID team of third-part solution that you can find here: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/.

Choose what suits best your needs.

Notice that they warn you:

> We have setup a code repository for gathering libraries and other supporting examples. While several of these libraries have been tested, they are maintained by members of the OpenID community and are not necessarily known to work.